# AAAI \includegraphics undefined control sequence

Tags: packages

I searched a lot about an issue I'm facing when I'm trying to insert `\includegraphics` to my aaai latex document. I'm using the online editor so you may trace the error easier. Here is my sample

```
\documentstyle[aaai]{article}
\bibliographystyle{aaai}
\author{xxx}
\title{xxx}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \nocite{*}
  \section{xxx}
\begin{figure}
     \includegraphics{fish}
  \caption{This is a fish.}
\end{figure}

  \bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting undefined control sequence.
I'm using `aaai.sty` so I can't include any package. If there is any way to include aaai as a class this may solve the problem, any suggestion please?

Regards,

Comment: `\includegraphics` is defined in the `graphicx` package so you need `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you,
I solve it by changing
\documentstyle[aaai]{article}

to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aaai}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Because when using `\documentstyle` it will not allow you to use any package

Thnks for the hint

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that you had `\documentstyle` absolutely no latex2e document should ever use that!!!!  It is the old latex2.09 command and is just there for compatibility with documents written before 1993. To see it being used this century is very weird.